# What is the correct way to use string index on a BeautifulSoup type?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to scrape JSON from a html web page.
However, when trying to extract the json part using the find function I get an error:

> Unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'

My code:

```
primary_url = "example.com"

page = requests.get(primary_url, auth=('user', 'pass'), headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

data  = soup.select("[type='text/javascript']")[40]

object_start = data[data.find('dealDetails'):data.find('responseMetadata') -1]
object_start = replace_right(object_start, ",", "", 1)
object_start = '{\n"' + object_start + '}'

prettified = json.loads(object_start)
```

The error is on line 8:

```
object_start = data[data.find('dealDetails'):data.find('responseMetadata') -1]
```

The type of data variable is bs4, I tried converting it into a string but it doesn't work.

Comment: `data.find('responseMetadata')` return None

Comment: @balderman
Yeah, it returns None even when the word does exist.

Comment: You need to share the `data` if you want us to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by adding this line of code:

```
data = str(data)
```

Thanks to everyone